# Query a specific intent Dialogflow apiv2

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I found an example that can determinate witch intent is trigger given a text
but I need to make almost the same, the only different is that I want to trigger a specific intent.

This is the example that I found, but is not what I need.

I am using the library of dialogflow to the new apiv2

```
def detect_intent_texts(project_id, session_id, texts, language_code):
"""Returns the result of detect intent with texts as inputs.

Using the same `session_id` between requests allows continuation
of the conversaion."""
session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
print('Session path: {}\n'.format(session))

for text in texts:
    text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(
        text=text, language_code=language_code)

    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)

    response = session_client.detect_intent(
        session=session, query_input=query_input)

    print('=' * 20)
    print('Query text: {}'.format(response.query_result.query_text))
    print('Detected intent: {} (confidence: {})\n'.format(
        response.query_result.intent.display_name,
        response.query_result.intent_detection_confidence))
    print('Fulfillment text: {}\n'.format(
        response.query_result.fulfillment_text))
```

Answer (score 3):

Take this answer as a complement to the one by Prasoon, who already oriented you in the right direction, but I will provide some additional information that may be more helpful for you in your use case.

I see that you are working over [the basic Dialogflow API V2 example](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library), using the [Python Dialogflow Client Library](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-python-client-v2) (you will find the complete reference for that library in [this other link](http://dialogflow-python-client-v2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)).

As per the documentation on the [migration from API V1 to V2](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-mapping#query), the `/query` calls in V1 are translated as `detectIntent` in V2, which you is being used in the sample code you shared in your question. The `detectIntent` method specifies the input of the query in its [`queryInput` field](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent#request-body), which can include an event that specifies which intent to trigger.

Knowing this, let's move to the Python client reference. There, you will be able to find a [`dialogflow.types.EventInput` class](http://dialogflow-python-client-v2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gapic/v2/types.html#dialogflow_v2.types.EventInput), which you can use to define an [Event](https://dialogflow.com/docs/events) in order to invoke specific intents of your choice.

With all this information in mind, you should start my defining the Events of your choice, and then adding an `EventInput` to your queries through the `detectInput` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a specific Intent using Events in dialogflow. Please documentation at [Events Link](https://dialogflow.com/docs/events).

> Events is a feature that allows you to invoke intents by an event name instead of a user query.
>
> First, you define event names in intents. Then, you can trigger these
>   intents by sending a /query request containing an event parameter.